# create custom master page in SP 2010 with top navigation,images

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, custom-masterpage, homepage

i wanted to create a custom master page  with the kind of UI as shown below in my SP 2010 site collection.I dont have access to web appln level,i have been provided access  upto site collection admin level only.

[image: homepage1]

is there any inbuilt, free master page templates for `SP 2010`  available such that i will modify here n there ,to achieve this.

What I did till now :

- Went to SP D 2010 and copied the v4.master and tried to edit
- the issue I faced is, when i tried to set up a  logo, thats residing in `siteassets` is , logo was missing .
- Went to F12 in the browser but under the s4-title  tag , there was no text .
  it was missing or some strange happened!
- I am not sure how to create a banner like stuff on top navigation and  create top navigation entries within the `squares/cube kind of images`

Answer (score 1):

Site collection permission is all you need to create custom master pages.

As a starting point you can use - https://startermasterpages.codeplex.com/

You need SharePoint Designer 2010 by the way.